# How can I make "filter: drop shadow" a rainbow gradient?

Tags: css, png, dropshadow

I'm still a beginner at CSS, so I apologize if this sounds silly.
I have a PNG image, and want it to have a drop-shadow; using the filter: drop-shadow property, this is
[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLlaZ.png), & [this is the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmhNl.png) 
I'm happy with the result, though I'd like to have it as a rainbow, horizontal gradient. Is that possible?

[I have this, but it works as a box shadow. Which is not what I want..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNLuH.png)

Answer (score 2):

https://codepen.io/devang47/pen/PoKwNbg

```
img{
    height: 100px;
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 4px #FF0000) 
        drop-shadow(5px 5px 4px #FF7F00)  
        drop-shadow(5px 5px 4px #FFFF00)  
        drop-shadow(5px 5px 4px #00FF00)  
        drop-shadow(5px 5px 4px #0000FF)  
        drop-shadow(5px 5px 4px #2E2B5F)  
        drop-shadow(5px 5px 4px #8B00FF) ;
}
```

This is the the proper implementation of the drop shadow, however, if you want to make a proper gradient, you have to add more drop shadow filters.